# Smart pointers and avoid manual memory management when using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, signals-slots, qsharedpointer

I have the following class which calls some HTTP API request to a server:

```
class NetworkRequest : public QObject {

public:
    NetworkRequest(QNetworkAccessManager* netManager):
        m_netManager(netManager){}

    void send(QUrl const &url){
        QNetworkRequest request(url);
        auto reply = m_netManager->get(request);
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [this, reply](){
            // do some stuff with reply (like if url is redirected)
            if(isRedirected(reply)){
                // we have to delete the reply and send a new one
                QUrl newUrl;
                // somehow get the new url;
                reply->deleteLater();
                send(newUrl);
            }
            else{
                reply->setParent(this); // so that it will be deleted when an instance of this class is deleted
                emit completed(reply);
            }
        });
    }

signals:
    void completed(QNetworkReply* reply);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_netManager;
    bool isRedirected(QNetworkReply * reply){
        bool yes = false;

        /* process the process reply and determine yes is true or false
        ....
        **/
        return yes;
    }
};
```

I use the class in this way:

```
auto req = new NetworkRequest(nm);
req->send("http://someurl.com");
connect(req, &NetworkRequest::completed, randomClass, &RandomClass::slot);

// in RandomClass::slot I call NetworkRequest::deleteLater() when I finished with the network data
```

Now this clearly involves some manual memory management and I have to be careful to not forget deleting the raw pointers. I was wondering if the code above could be written using `QSharedPointer`  (or even `std::shared_ptr`) and replacing:

```
        auto reply = m_netManager->get(request);
```

with:

```
        auto smartReply = QSharedPointer<QNetworkReply>(m_netManager->get(request));
```

then replace all instances of `reply` with `smartReply.get()` and then forget about manually deleting reply objects. However, it is unclear to me if the shared pointer will automatically  delete the objects because between the time frame that I call `send()` and the signal `QNetworkReply::finished`, would the smart pointer know that the raw pointer is still in use? Also when I delete an instance of `NetworkRequest` will the shared pointer automatically delete the `QNetworkReply` it owns?

Comment: Qt docs say, that you should delete the reply, however not directly in the slot, but using `deleteLater()`. It looks like you do it properly in your code.

Comment: @vahancho could a `QSharedPointer` with a custom deleter  be used then? (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#QSharedPointer-2)

Comment: It may be used, but I don't see a point for using a shared pointer. Who shares the pointer? In this case the scoped or unique pointer will be more appropriate, IMO.

Comment: but wouldn't the scope end before the `QNetworkReply::finished` is emitted?

Comment: The scope would be the `send()` function. But anyways, I would't use smart pointers to manage the lifetime of pointers that aren't created by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some thinking I came up with a solution. The main problem I wanted to solve was to avoid deleting my `QNetworkReply*` object manually, instead I wanted it to be automatically destroyed when an instance of `NetworkRequest` is deleted. In order to achieve this, I used a `std::unique_ptr` as a private member of my `NetworkRequest` class so when the class is destroyed, the `unique_ptr` automatically cleans the object in memory. Furthermore, by default `std::unique_ptr` deletes the object it hold upon reassignment, so whenever I call the `send` function in my, I can assign a new object to the smart pointer and the previous object in memory will get deleted automatically. One thing to notice, was the Qt docs recommend that `QNetworkReply*` should be deleted using `QObject::deleteLater()` (it is not fully clear to me why this is the case), in order to do this one can just use a custom deleter.
So in my code, I declared a private member as following:

```
private:
    struct deleteLaterDeletor
    {
        void operator()(QObject *object) const
        {
            if(object) {
                object->deleteLater();
            }
        }
    };

    using ReplyPointer = std::unique_ptr<QNetworkReply, deleteLaterDeletor>;

    ReplyPointer m_reply;
```

Then in my `send` function:

```
        m_reply = ReplyPointer(mNetManager->get(netRequest));
```

Obviously, in the signature of signal and slots I have to pass the raw pointer (`m_reply.get()`).

(`QSharedPointer` can also be used instead of `std::unique_ptr`)